# How to run a DirectX Game through Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, uwp, directx, command-prompt, directx-11

I have a program for DirectX, written in C++. I have compiled it through Visual Studio, but I want to run that program through the Command Prompt. I tried to run a [Sample Direct3D Game](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Simple3DGameDX) from the Command Prompt just to be sure, but it didn't work either. This Game works fine when I build it from Visual Studio 19 or Visual Studio 17, but I am not able to run it from the Command Prompt. Everytime I do, a window pops up with the following message.

> The code execution cannot proceed because `MSVCP140D_APP.dll` was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

The same message is displayed about `vccorlib140d_app.Dll`, `CONCRT140D_APP.dll`, and `VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll`. However, I face no such issues when running the same program through Visual Studio. I've tried almost everything that I could find about this issue, but I couldn't solve it. The `.exe` file that I tried to run, is in the path: `..Direct3D_game_sample\cpp\x64\Debug\Simple3DGameDX`

I also tried running a [simple OpenCV program](https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/) written in C++ to read and display a sample video file, but couldn't do so either. It runs perfectly through Visual Studio, but not through the Command Prompt. The OpenCV program returns the following errors.

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:940)
warning: vtest.avi (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:941)
OpenCV(3.4.9) Error: Bad argument (CAP_IMAGES: cannot find starting number (in the name of file): vtest.avi) in cv::icvExtractPattern, file C:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp, line 246
[ERROR:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_Images(filename.c_str())): raised OpenCV exception:
OpenCV(3.4.9) C:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:246: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES:cannot find starting number (in the name of file): vtest.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

PS: I'm running Windows 10 on my machine and the Sample DirectX Game App uses DirectX 11.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since your program is using the `MSVCP140D_APP.dll` version of the CRT, that means you built a Universal Windows Platform app (i.e. a [UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)). You can't run such an application as a Win32 application from the command-line and have it work.  All the samples on the [Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/) GitHub are UWP apps.

You can use Powershell Commands to install and launch an appx package built from Visual Studio. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/?view=win10-ps).

If what you want is a Win32 desktop application, then you need to build a different program. See [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki) for Win32 VS templates in the style of the "UWP" templates.